# Able to ssh to server using only one domain yet they all use the same ip

Tags: laravel, nginx, vue.js, ssh, openssh

Thanks in advance.

I have setup a server in which I intend to host a couple of applications but something weird is happening, I have bought a couple of domains which I have all mapped to the same ip address, but now when trying to ssh to that server only one of the domains goes through, the rest don't.

Someone please explain why this is happening and what I could have probably done wrong

Comment: Hey @john, can you tell us a little bit more about how you set this up? When you say you mapped the domains to the IP, I assume all domain names are DNS A entries to the same IP address? Or some are C entries to an A DNS entry? I also assume you're using OpenSSH? Anything particular you did in OpenSSH's configuration that deviates from its default? What exactly happens when you connect with an ssh client to a hostname that does not work? Do those connection attempts show up in the OpenSSH server logs? Cheers, Tobias

Comment: Hey @john, also, since your question is related to SSH, maybe tag the question as 'ssh', 'openssh' or appropriate?

Comment: Have you run a NSLOOKUP to verify that these domains are actually pointing to the same IP? 

How long ago were they set up? Have you given the DNS enough time to propagate?

Comment: @Tobias thanks, well, I am using a class A IP. I did not configure openSSH in anyway, I only installed ssh and that was it, was able to use ssh

Comment: @john So, all those A DNS entries point to the correct IP and resolve correctly from the client machine you're trying to connect? If yes, can you peek into the SSH server logs and check if the unsuccessful connection attempts to the other host names show up in the logs? The logs (on most Unix systems) should be somewhere in /var/logs on the server. Best place to start on the server: tail -500 /var/log/auth.log | grep 'sshd'

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct that you are attempting to connect to the different domains via different saved configurations in your SSH terminal app. If so, check that you have connected each of those configurations to the appropriate private key. And of course check any other settings you may have needed in those configurations.

For example, make sure that if the host name for the working one is `<username>@<domainOne>` then the others are not simply `<domainTwo.com>`. (Errors like this can be hidden in some SSH terminals if the domain is very long.)